# Link in UIWebView seen as UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, safari, webview

I am trying to open my link in an external Safari window, but for some reason it is not recognizing my link as a link.  I am using the following code, the problem is that it is seeing my link as an **UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther**

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

What would cause it to think my link is a UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens when javascript code which loads a new url is called when you touch a link. Not using `<a href="link">`